# Select different column names when loop thru snowflake tables from Python

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a `.py` script that loop thru several `ids` and pull columns from each table.

```
for i in range(len(ids)): 
    sql='select col1, col2 from table_{}'.format(ids[i])
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, snowflake_connection)
```

However, what I am stuck at is that not all tables have `col2`. For example, if only `table_01` have `col2` , `table_02` did not, then I would get an error with above script. Is there a simple way to tell snowflake that if `col2` exist, then pull it, otherwise just create a column called `col2` and fill it with `NULL`s?

Comment: Why don't use a try except block?

Comment: @D4NieLDev Getting `sql compilation error` by using try except

Answer (score 0):

We can write a function in python  to pull columns from table ,passing as table name as an argument and using  below code in function which pull comma separated values and return to function call .So it will dynamic col list and you can apply in your sql.

```
Select listagg(column_name, ', ') within group (ORDER BY column_name) cols_lst from information_schema.columns  ref_cols where ref_cols.table_name='TEST' ;
```